# How do I use CouchDB as backend database to a MeteorJS app, instead of the default MongoDB?

Tags: meteor, couchdb, pouchdb

Really would like to use [CouchDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CouchDB), and maybe make the [Meteor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_%28web_framework%29) app get data updates via [Meteor Publish and Subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#publishandsubscribe). But can't seem to figure out how to connect the [Meteor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_%28web_framework%29) app with [CouchDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CouchDB) instead of [the default](http://docs.meteor.com/#dataandsecurity) [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB). Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now you can use CouchDb with Meteor as a drop in replacement for MongoDB. The guys at Cloudant have create Couchdb integration from Meteor.

Best thing is that its API resembles to that on Mongo in Meteor.
Here is the package and details : https://github.com/cloudant/meteor-couchdb/

Enjoy :)

Comment: Mongo API on a CouchDB does not seem like the BEST thing, but I can see some value in there, too

Answer (score 8):

Especially as [this (Meteor+CouchDB) seems to be increasingly not happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788769/how-do-i-use-couchdb-as-backend-database-to-a-meteorjs-app-instead-of-the-defau#comment-38165255),
**[PouchDB](http://google.com/search?q=pouchdb) is the best nearest alternative that I've  found**, and so I plan to start with it.

[PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) notables I find:

1. ability to sync with the 2 major CouchDB hosts, with [nice intro by (my favorite) Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/blog/pouchdb/), plus your own hosting per http://pouchdb.com/faq.html
2. [very cross-platform](http://pouchdb.com/learn.html), as compared [to Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#appcache), also has [nice compatability breakdowns](http://pouchdb.com/adapters.html#pouchdb_in_the_browser) plus supports Safari Desktop plus:
3. its client emulation of the server database feels stronger and further along than Meteror indeed [PouchDB can be its own server (running on Node)](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server),
4. it has [an impressive list of powerful external projects including plugins](http://pouchdb.com/external.html) -take a peek, including:

   1. "Peer Pouch" (p2p --doubt Meteor can do that)
   2. Full-text and spacial search
   3. Lacks [Meteor's impressive authentication (including Meetup accounts!)](http://docs.meteor.com/#dataandsecurity-authentication), but basic authentication seems there and already strong with CouchDB (per  https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication ), and [that mentions](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication#project-status) impressive authentication coming: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Persona support.
   4. Lack's [Meteor's live (self-updating) templates](http://docs.meteor.com/#livehtmltemplates) but from the plugins, has 3 "MV* Adapters" including similar and terribly popular AngularJS.
5. [Performance-wise it seems to mostly beat leading competitor Couchbase Lite](http://www.mircozeiss.com/pouchdb-vs-couchbase-lite-a-performance-review/)

Comment: Do also take a look at hood.ie. Couch-oriented and has many built-ins comp with Meteor.

Answer (score 6):

[The Data section of the Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#data) (last paragraph) mention substituting other DB engines for Mongo by writing a driver.  Here's the quote:

> You can substitute another database for MongoDB by providing a server-side database driver and/or a client-side cache that implements an alternative API. The mongo-livedata is a good starting point for such a project.

Comment: What is this "mongo-livedata" thing? Where can I find more about it?

Comment: Your initial link (to the data section of the meteor docs) has rotted.

Comment: ...AND the information that I quoted no longer appears, I can't vouch for any information I originally provided after the recent changes in Meteor.

Comment: Agree. Quote's in https://web.archive.org/web/20120705173127/http://docs.meteor.com but after that,Archives empty; +just did Google Search(site:meteor.com (server-side database driver) OR (substitute another database)) but in results(2pgs) only found again http://docs.meteor.com/#dataandsecurity saying "support for other databases is coming in the future" + QUOTE-REPLACEMENT "Future releases will include support for other databases" BUT 0 MORE, except recently they (instead?)improving their*MongoDB*support(w/ "sort"&"limit") http://meteor.com/blog/2014/03/18/meteor-072-scaling-realtime-mongodb

Comment: Also see hood.ie which is a little like meteor but backed with couch.